# compilation-mode: default-directory != src-root

Tags: compilation, compilation-mode

I have `subDirA` with source code `foo.rs`.
To compile code in bash I need:

```
$ cd subDirA
$ some-compile-command
```

But problem is that compiler invoked via `some-compile-command`
prints errors in such format: `subDirA/foo.rs:26:57`
instead of `foo.rs:26:57` and emacs always ask where to find `foo.rs`,
which is very unproductive.

I suppose I can solve my problem with bash script that run in `../subDirA`,
but invoke `some-compile-command` in `subDirA`.
But may be it is possible to solve problem on emacs level?

Does something like `(set compilation-mode-src-root-directory` exits?

I'm using Emacs 25.

Comment: If you call `M-x cd` and then set the `default-directory` of the buffer you are in to the directory you want and then call your compile command, or call `M-x eval-expression RET (setq default-directory "/your/desired/path/") RET` and then call your compile command, does that give you the desired result (abliet the current buffer has the wrong default-directory)?

Comment: Sounds like the first thing to fix is your compiler, which is referring to files in an unusual way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I give a recipe for reproduction of your problem (hopefully I understood it right). Afterwards I will present a solution.

## Recipe for problem reproduction

1. Put the following C++ source code into `~/tmp/subDirA/test.cc`. (The file local variable `compilation-post-dir` is a preparation for the solution.)

```cc
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world.\n";
    unknown_command();
    return 0;
}

/*
  Local Variables:
  compile-command: "make all"
  compilation-post-dir: ".."
  End:
 */
```

2. Put the following source code into the file `~/tmp/subDirA/Makefile`.

```make
#!/bin/bash

.phony: all
all:
    cd ..; g++ subDirA/test.cc
```

3. Switch to buffer `test.cc` and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile`. Accept the default input `make all` with <kbd>RET</kbd>.
4. The compilation gives you the following output in buffer `*compilation*`:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/tmp/subDirA/" -*-
Compilation started at Sat Jan 27 02:25:26

make all
cd ..; g++ subDirA/test.cc
subDirA/test.cc: In function 'int main()':
subDirA/test.cc:5:18: error: 'unknown_command' was not declared in this scope
  unknown_command();
                  ^
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Sat Jan 27 02:25:26
```

5. Clicking on `subDirA/test.cc:5:18: error: ...` in the compilation buffer asks you for the location of `subDirA/test.cc`. That is what you **don't want**.

## Possible solution

There are some restrictions for the solution.

1. The default directory of the compilation buffer at the time point when the compilation process starts must be the same as that one for the source file. Otherwise the `Makefile` would be searched for in a wrong directory.
2. After the compilation process has been started the default directory must be changed to the one which is given by the `cd`-command in the `Makefile`. I name that directory `compilation-post-dir`.

The required `compilation-post-dir` can result from very complicated constructions in the `Makefile`. I don't try to generate it automatically it must be given by the user. SHe can set it through the file-local variable `compilation-post-dir` as demonstrated in the above example.

The following lisp code manages the change of directory after the start of the compilation process in the compilation buffer.

```el
(require 'compile)
(defvar-local compilation-post-dir nil
  "Directory becoming the new default-directory after `compilation-start'
if non-nil.")

(defun compilation-post-dir (&rest _args)
  "Setting `default-directory' after `compilation-start'.
Can be an advice for `compilation-start'."
  (when (and (stringp compilation-post-dir)
         (buffer-live-p compilation-last-buffer))
    (let ((post-dir compilation-post-dir))
      (with-current-buffer compilation-last-buffer
    (cd post-dir)))))

(advice-add 'compilation-start :after #'compilation-post-dir)
```

With that code installed emacs finds the buffer `test.cc` when you click on `subDirA/test.cc:5:18: error: ...` in the compilation buffer.

You can install the code in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) if you like it.